# junit test math calculations

Tags: math, junit

I have methods with operations on vectors ( like dot products ) or solving equations of circle and line. Can somebody suggest me how to test it ? I can calculate result on paper or using programs like wolfram and then check if results are the same, but is it the best option ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is how testing is supposed to be. You get the results independently and compare to your actual program.

Your question isn't completely clear to me, maybe you can describe in more detail what cases you want to test. In general you try to get as many corner cases as you can think of. For our dot product:

- some simple cases with different sizes from 1 to 10
- vector of size zero
- orthogonal vectors
- one of the vectors is the null vector
- vectors of different sizes (check error handling)

Answer (score 1):

Checking the results against a set of pre-calculated set of values is the correct way to do it, yes. The tricky part is to choose examples that are likely representative to all classes of input values. For example for the circle and the line you should probably check the following cases:

- No intersection
- Two intersections
- One intersection with precisely calculable values using floating point numbers, like (0,-1) for the circle with radius 1 and center (0,0) and the line through the points (0,-1) and (1,-1)
- One intersection with irrational value (you would have to question yourself what you expect the results to be in such cases, for example whether you want check if the two intersection points are so close to each other that you consider them to be the same)
- Each of them rotated by 90 degree (for example to find out that you do not support vertical lines)
- Illegal inputs, like circles with negative radius